# Angular JS 1.6 routing

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to make routing in angular js 1.6 but it is giving below error. By default home page is loaded properly but when I try to navigate two.html it is throwing error.

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:19933
at angular.js:16843
at m.$digest (angular.js:17982)
at m.$apply (angular.js:18280)
at angular.js:1912
at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
at c (angular.js:1910)
at Pc (angular.js:1930)
at ue (angular.js:1815)
```

This is my app.js code

```
var app = angular.module("jasmineKarmaDemo", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/home.html"
    })
    .when("/two", {
        templateUrl : "two.html"
    })
    .otherwise("/two", {
        templateUrl : "views/two.htm"
    })
}]);
```

This is HTML code

```
<header>
        <div>
            <a href="#/">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#two">Two</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

It is working fine with angular js 1.5 version.
Should I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error you getting says one of templates `views/home.html`, `two.html`, `views/two.htm` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski by mistake I was given wrong URL for /two. Now I correct it, the error is solve but it is not redirect to two.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url are prefixed with `!` in 1.6 version - [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ngRoute)

Something like this:

```
<a ng-href="#!/url">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your second route "/two",template url is "two.html", but according to other routes, I'm assuming that you've missed "views/" part, so that template doesn't exist.

Also, I think your otherwise would be better like this:

```
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/two'});
```

or is that different view?